How to transfer data using Zero-ETL to a writable DB in Redshift
Im using Zero-Etl to move my data from Aurora to Redshift. But this moves the data to a read-only database. How do I then move my data to a full access database?
I have tried creating a materialized view, but it needs a manual refresh every time. I need my data as close to real time as possible and setting a refresh to run every minute for every table doesnt seem like a smart option.
